# Can't #foreach loop with my simple structure

Tags: liferay, velocity, liferay-theme, liferay-velocity

I'm having trouble looping through the social media links in my repeatable Authors structure.

Here is what the structure looks like:

[image]

The name field for the Authors section is `authors` and the name field for the social media links is `social_media`. The name field for each of the individual links are just their field names, `facebook`, `twitter`, etc. The `Social Media` field is a separator field if that makes any difference.

This is the code I'm trying to use to loop through the social media links:

```
#set($articleAuthors = $authors.getSiblings())


#foreach($author in $articleAuthors)

  <ul class="author-social-links">

    #foreach($link in $author.social_media)
      <li>$link.getData()</li>
    #end

  </ul>

#end
```

This is what it results in:

[image]

It kind of works, but why is the `$link.getData()` being added to the `ul` as well?

Comment: Can your $link.getData() be null in any case?

Comment: I guess it technically could if I left any of the four fields blank, but in this case they were all filled which is why I don't understand it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should try adding [Quiet Reference Notation](https://velocity.apache.org/engine/releases/velocity-1.5/user-guide.html#quietreferencenotation) like- $!{link.getData()}.

This will avoid getting this value printed when not actually populated.

Comment: Thanks. I'm not sure why this was happening as all the fields were populated.

Using Quiet Reference Notation still made a blank `li` be created, so I just went with an `#if` statement to check if the field wasn't null before creating the `li`.

Comment: Well, actually that's exacly what you needed as pointed out by @PrakashKumar

Comment: Right, but why are there null values if all of the fields are being filled in?

Comment: I'm sure some of the fields are not being filled in because of some reason specific to your project. With the info you have shared, it looks difficult to figure that out. IMHO, you should ask a new question regarding this specifically tagged with liferay tags so that someone with appropriate expertise can take a call on that.